# Implicit conversion of class tree

Tags: scala

I have a set of traits/class like:

```
trait Parent
case class ChildA(str: String) extends Parent
case class ChildB(str: String) extends Parent

object Parent {
   implicit def toA(str: String) = ChildA(str)
   implicit def toB(str: String) = ChildB(str)
}
```

and this works ok for the case of conversion for `ChildA` or `ChildB`.

On my tests I want to have an additional rule that if a method receives a `Parent` it do something like:

```
implicit def toParent(str: String) = ChildA(str)
```

How do I do this? the compiler seems to get confused since it can choose multiple conversions to Parent.

Comment: An instance of a child always contains properties of the parent. What are you trying to do? Looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `toA` to be chosen over `toB` for conversions to `Parent` you can use the mechanism of implicit priorities. An implicit has a lower priority if it is inherited from a class or trait.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Parent
case class ChildA(str: String) extends Parent
case class ChildB(str: String) extends Parent

trait LowerPiorityImplicits {
  implicit def toB(str: String) = ChildB(str)
}

object Parent extends LowerPiorityImplicits {
   implicit def toA(str: String) = ChildA(str)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

warning: there were two feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
defined trait Parent
defined class ChildA
defined class ChildB
defined trait LowerPiorityImplicits
defined object Parent

scala> val foo: ChildA = "foo"
foo: ChildA = ChildA(foo)

scala> val foo: ChildB = "foo"
foo: ChildB = ChildB(foo)

scala> val foo: Parent = "foo"
foo: Parent = ChildA(foo)
```